# How to efficiently store video frames in memory

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to load all the frames of a video for analysis, things such as average pixel value across all frames for background extraction, but the memory requirement is killing me.

When I load the frames in memory in uint8, they take up ~2.8gb of memory. I have looked into libraries such as pims, but I would need to interactively perform operations on the entire set of frames on the fly.

How can I efficiently hold the frame while still being able to use Numpy element-wise array operations?

Comment: Some kind of nemory mapping might help https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

Comment: You need to be 100% sure that you need them all in memory. Computing the average iteratively is certainly a better approach.

Comment: Maybe clarifying the use case a bit would help. I would like to create a GUI that would allow the user to load a video and have its frames arranged in a timeline. The user then will be able to do some manipulations, such as increasing the brightness of the entire video, and the changes should be reflected in the frames.

Andras, I will check out the mapping approach today.

Comment: Unless you intend to work with just short clips, the amount of raw image data will just be too large for it to be practical to keep it all in memory. Even on disk it might be too much (FullHD @24FPS is ~140MB/second) to be able to take advantage of memory mapping. Hence, the efficient way is not to keep all the frames decoded in the RAM.